# Как разделить элементы массива на родительские и дочерние?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Есть массив типа

`category = ["Комплектующие для ПК", "ПО", "ОС"]`

**Кол-во элемент может приходить разное.**
По ним создаются `Category` из `.csv` файла.
В данном массиве `category` нужно чтобы `category[0]` был родителем, а `category[1]` - дочерней категорией, но родителем для `category[2]`
Т.е. Комплектующие для ПК => ПО => ОС

Использую гем Ancestry

Для двух элементов работает такой код (хоть и некрасивый):

```
  last = nil

  csv.each do |row| # в row строки из таблицы 
    base = row[6].split('/')[0] # здесь получаю первый элемент массива
    parent_category = Category.create!(name: base) if Category.where(name: base).first.nil? # Создаю базовую категорию

    row[6].split('/').each do |category| # перебираю категории
      if Category.where(name: category).first.nil? # если категории не существует
        last = Category.create!(name: parent_category) if last == nil # то создаю базовую
        # если базовая есть то создаю ей дочерние
        child = Category.create!(name: category, ancestry: Category.where(name: base).first.id) if last != nil
      end
    end
  end
```

Подскажите как реализовать такой код для любого кол-ва элементов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
csv.each do |row| # в row строки из таблицы 
  names = row[6].split('/') # получаем массив имён для категорий
  (names.length - 1).times do |n| 
    parent_id = Category.find_or_create_by(name: names[n]).id
    Category.find_or_create_by(name: names[n+1], parent_id: parent_id)
  end
end
```

Как это работает: перебираем массив имён и последовательно создаём пары `parent-child`.
Метод [`find_or_create_by`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by) проверяет, есть ли категория с нужным именем (и родителем), если нет, то создаёт её. Проверьте, должно работать